# Spark on Yarn: How to prevent spark user-cache from growing in size really quickly

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Spark user cache seems to grow really fast in terms of space utilization. I had a HDP 2.3.4 set up which was configured to use local-dirs that are local to the individual slave nodes.

The slave nodes disk partition that was set up for local use on the instances quickly got filled up. I moved the local-dirs location to within HDFS in the non-DFS space partition. This helped scale out my application significantly but it seems like it only moved the problem out to a much later stage when my cluster is processing over 100M events. At this stage the HDFS utilization is close to 90% with most of the utilization coming from the non-DFS part of HDFS (so assuming no replication?). This causes all yarn node managers to stall and the job to fail.

Questions:

- Is there a way to increase the speed at which the user-cache can be made to expire quickly?
- Is adding user-cache to HDFS a good idea?
- The cache space utilization seems more than the data that's being used to do the analytics. Could there be any other reasons this could grow that quickly?